# AWS boto3 paginator: Get subset of a bucket and exclude certain 'directories'

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I have an s3 'directory' that I want to paginate through and grab all the keys.
The keys are like this:

```
'myPrefix/output1.csv'
'myPrefix/output2.csv'
'myPrefix/output3.csv'
'myPrefix/inputs/'
'myPrefix/solutions/'
```

I would like to only grab the top level keys, so all the `.csv` files, and avoid grabbing the `inputs/` and `solutions/` directories

I can grab all the keys in my S3 bucket which I do like this:

```
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
paginator = s3.get_paginator('list_objects_v2')
pages = paginator.paginate(Bucket='mybucket',
                           Prefix= 'myPrefix'
solutions_files = []
for page in pages:
    solutions_files += [obj['Key'] for obj in page['Contents']]
```

Is there a way to exclude certain keys within my bucket? Or only grab the top-level files?

Comment: "top-level" doesn't exist in s3 as it's a flat filesystem and what appears to be a directory is just part of the object name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on your structure, you might use delimiter param in conjunction with prefix in `list_objects_v2` call: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ListingKeysHierarchy.html

Otherwise you can filter in your script, you already do it in a way.

```
for page in pages:
    solutions_files.extend(
        [obj['Key'] for obj in page['Contents'] if obj['Key'].endswith('.csv')]
    )
```

Change the condition to whatever fits your use case.